# Custom Routes in UI Router Angular JS (URL Shortcuts)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have some states which look like this:

```
.state('patient.patient-login', {
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
})
.state('patient.patient-login.practiceID', {
  url: "/patient-login/:practiceID",
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: "views/patient-login.html"
})
```

The problem is the `:practiceID` variable can be quite long and not user friendly, I want to give a user the ability to create a custom URL which is tied to the practice ID, for example on Facebook when you create an account you start out with a profile URL like this: http://facebook.com/123456789 but then you can change it to http://facebook.com/whateveryouwant

So essentially I want to accomplish something like this:

```
POINTER
http://domain.com/companyname > http://domain.com/#/patient-login/companyid

ANOTHER EXAMPLE
http://domain.com/ladentist > http://domain.com/#/patient-login/-85k3jfGEioltold
```

I was able to allow a user to set their `unique url` but I'm not sure how to even start to setup the routing like that?

Comment: Consider setting up a route on your website such as domain.com/link/:slug. Somewhere in your app, you'll have a mapping between shorthand, and full URLs, and you can have this controller handle the routing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the rest of your project looks like but you could update your state to handle both id's and unique urls in the `resolve` property. Which would roughly look like this:

```
.state('patient.patient-login.practiceID', {
  url: "/patient-login/:practice",
  scope: true,
  templateUrl: "views/patient-login.html",
  resolve: {
    patientData: [
      '$stateParams',
      'practiceSvc',    // replace practiceSvc with however you are fetching data from your server

      function($stateParams, practiceSvc) {
        // check if the :practice param is an id or unique url
        if ($stateParams.practice === /* id check */) {
          // Call to API - get practice by ID
          return practiceSvc.getByID($stateParams.practice);
        } else {
          // Call to API - get practice by unique url
          return practiceSvc.getBySlug($stateParams.practice);
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

This assumes you can tell the difference between a unique url and an id. If you can't do that you could update it to check for the id first then the unique url if no practice is found.

Comment: How could I do this from the root URL (example: `http://domain.com/id` vs `http://domain.com/patient-login/id`

Comment: If you mean `http://domain.com/id` to `http://domain.com/#/patient-login/id` you might want to handle that via a server-side wildcard route. I'm just not sure if that will interfere with the angular routes (although you can probably check for the # and be fine).

Another option would be to create a subfolder at the same level as your main `index.html` file and put a new index.html file inside of it that will just handle redirects for patient login: `login/index.html`. Inside the `login/index.html` would be a redirect function that just looks at the url and transforms it to the angular route.

Comment: that's a good idea, how would I make the sub-folder dynamic though, the URL needs to be based on the company name `example: http://domain.com/companyname/`

Comment: The static URL would be `http://domain.com/login/companyname`. If you want it fully dynamic you probably want a server-side solution.  With that said you could have a script in your main index.htl file that checks the URL and then redirects or loads angular. In which case https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap would be worth looking into.